# Running total per id within sliding time window in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a query that can tell me number of idObj for the given idTest for Yesterday, 2 day before and 3 day before.

Number of idObj flagged 2 day before should include idObj flagged Yesterday i.e. It only should display number of idObj flagged yesterday as well as 2 day before.
Number of idOjb flagged 3 day before should include idObj flagged Yesterday, 2 day before and 3 day before.

I also need the name of the column as date instead of 'DayBeforeYest' and 'TwoDayBefore'.

Below is what I am looking for:

```
idTest    2013-06-29    2013-06-28    2013-06-27
104        9              7                 5
105        7              6             2
106        5              3             0
```

Here, on 2013-06-29, idObj counts includes those idObj that has been flagged on only 2013-06-29. On 2013-06-28, idObj count includes those idObj that has been flagged on 2013-06-29 and on 2013-06-28. On 2013-06-27, idObj count includes those idObj that has been flagged on 
2013-06-29, 2013-06-28 and 2013-06-27. Therefore, 3 days ago column will have less idObj counts compared to yesterday.

Query

```
create table tblTest (dateFact date, idTest int, idObj int);

insert into tblTest values
('2013-06-29', 104, 4433), ('2013-06-29', 105, 3345), ('2013-06-29', 106, 5543),
('2013-06-28', 104, 4433), ('2013-06-28', 105, 3345), ('2013-06-28', 106, 4356),
('2013-06-27', 104, 3439), ('2013-06-07', 105, 3345), ('2013-06-07', 106, 8955);
```

Below is the query I came up with but it just counts number of idObj flagged on 2nd and 3rd day per idTest. It does not take into account of idObj flagged in prevous days. It also doesn't display column name in the date format.

```
select idTest, max(Yest) as Yest, max(DayBeforeYest) as DayBeforeYest,     max(TwoDayBefore) as TwoDayBefore from
(
(select idTest, count(idObj) as Yest, 0 as DayBeforeYest, 0 as TwoDayBefore from tblTest
where dateFact =date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 day) group by idTest)
union
(select idTest, 0 as Yest, count(idObj) DayBeforeYest, 0 as TwoDayBefore from tblTest
where dateFact = date_Sub(curdate(), interval 2 day) group by idTest)
union
(select idTest, 0 as Yest, 0 as DayBeforeYest , count(idObj) TwoDayBefore from tblTest
where dateFact = date_sub(curdate(), interval 3 day) group by idTest) )x
group by idTest;
```

Thank you!

====================================

Edited:

```
create table tblTest (dateFact date, idTest int, idObj int);

INSERT INTO tblTest
select CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY, 104, 4433 UNION ALL
SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY, 105, 3345 UNION ALL
SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY, 106, 5543 UNION ALL
SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY, 104, 4433 UNION ALL
SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY, 105, 3345 UNION ALL
SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY, 106, 4356 UNION ALL
SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY, 104, 3439 UNION ALL
SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY, 105, 3345 UNION ALL
SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY, 106, 8955;
```

For the given example, output should be as below:

```
idTest    2013-06-30    2013-06-29    2013-06-28
104         1           1                0
105         1           1                1
106         1           0                0
```

On 2013-06-30 for idTest 104, we have 1 idObj 4433. On 2013-06-29 for idTest 104 we have 1 idObj 4433 which is also in 2013-06-30 for idTest 104. 
On 2013-06-28 for idTest 104 we have 1 idObj 3439 which is not in either 2013-06-30 or 2013-06-29 for idTest 104. Therefore, you will see row values for 104 to be 1 1 0.

On 2013-06-30 for idTest 105, we have 1 idObj 3345. On 2013-06-29 for idTest 105 we have 1 idObj 3345 which is also in 2013-06-30 idTest 105.
On 2013-06-28 for idTest 105, we have 1 idObj 3345 which is also in 2013-06-30 and 2013-06-29. Therefore, you will see row values to be 1 1 1.

And so on...

On 2013-06-28, to count the idObj, it should be present in 2013-06-28, 213-06-29, 2013-06-30.
On 2013-06-29, to count the idObj, it should be present in 2013-06-29 and 2013-06-30.
On 2013-06-30, to count the idObj, it should be present in 2013-06-30.

Comment: I skipped over this question a couple of times before curiosity got the best of me. Can you add a more descriptive title?

Comment: what would you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED** To make column names to be dates you have to use dynamic SQL.

```sql
SET @sql = CONCAT(
'SELECT  idTest 
       , SUM(d1) `', DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY, '%Y-%m-%d'), 
       '`, SUM(d2 = 1 AND d1 = 1) `', DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY, '%Y-%m-%d'),
       '`, SUM(d3 = 1 AND d2 = 1 AND d1 = 1) `', DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY, '%Y-%m-%d'),
'`  FROM
(
  SELECT  idTest
         ,idObj
         ,SUM(CASE WHEN dateFact = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) d1
         ,SUM(CASE WHEN dateFact = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) d2
         ,SUM(CASE WHEN dateFact = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) d3
    FROM tblTest
   WHERE dateFact BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
   GROUP BY idTest, idObj
) q
 GROUP BY idTest');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Sample output:

```
| IDTEST | 2013-07-02 | 2013-07-01 | 2013-06-30 |
-------------------------------------------------
|    104 |          1 |          1 |          0 |
|    105 |          1 |          1 |          1 |
|    106 |          1 |          0 |          0 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85f7f0/1)** demo

To make life easier on client (calling) side you can wrap this code into a stored procedure

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test_report()
BEGIN
  -- put above mentioned code here
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And then use it

```sql
CALL sp_test_report();
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb809/1)** demo

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for the detail work.

What I am trying to do is count number of idObj for each idTest. Comparing yesterday's idObj count with 2 day before idObj and looking if there are any repeatitions.
Comparing 3 day before idObj count with yesterday and 2 day before idObj and looking if there are any repeatitions.

Therefore, 3 day before idObj count will have all idObj of yesterday and 2 day before and 3 day before.
2 day before idObj count will have idObj of yesterday and 2 day before.

Comment: @Rio. You're welcome. Can you explain your logic in detail on your sample data that you've posted? Please take one idTest (e.g. 104) and explain what how and why should be counted. Because right now it's incomprehensible. By *...to do is count number of idObj for each idTest...* do you mean distinct idObj per idTest per day or something else? What do you mean by *...comparing ... and looking if there are any repetitions*? If you counted ids for two days then how do mean to compare the results? If you provide detailed explanation we'll definitely fix the query to do exactly what you want.

Comment: @Rio is `(dateFact, idTest, idObj) unique? Meaning there is only one idObj per idTest per date?

Comment: There can be many idObj for each idTest, but for a single date they all will be unique per idTest. For a day e.g. 2013-06-30, for idTest 104, all idObj will be unique. 
Each idObj can also apprear in multiple idTest for a single date e.g. for 2013-06-30 there can be idObj 4433 in idTest 104 and 105. 

Thanks!